# RAM missing in live Linux environment

Tags: linux, memory, livecd

I have 4 GiB of RAM on my computer (1 x 4 GiB stick). When I run any live Linux distribution (I've tried Linux kernel 4.9, 5.9 and 5.10), `free -h` shows only 2.1 GiB total RAM. Everything else (UEFI, inxi, dmidecode, lshw) shows 4 GiB.

The interesting thing is that the computer has Manjaro (kernel 5.11) installed, and `free -h` in that shows all 4 GiB total RAM. I've tested the RAM by using over 80% of it at a time without errors.

On my other computer which also has 4 GiB RAM, the distributions show 4 GiB total RAM, so there's nothing wrong with the live distributions.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is the live-CD a 32-bit Linux? In that case this wouldn't be so unusual.

Comment: @Tonny - All the distributions and the computers are 64-bit. I didn't think recent kernels had 32-bit versions.

Comment: The kernel version means nothing. Please provide the output of `uname -a` for one of the live distributions where you see the error.

Comment: @DanielB - `Linux antix1 4.9.0-264-antix.1-amd64-smp #1 SMP PREEMPT Thur Apr 15 17:05:11 EEST 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux`